404 not found error in nginx whenever I hit API route
Dockerfile
FROM php:8.1.2-fpm-alpine3.15


RUN apk update && apk add libzip-dev icu-dev autoconf build-base


RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv \
           pcntl \
           intl \
           zip \
           pdo_mysql \
           exif


RUN apk add --no-cache libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev && \
docker-php-ext-configure gd \
   --with-freetype \
   --with-jpeg && \
docker-php-ext-install gd && \
apk del --no-cache freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev zlib-dev


RUN apk add --update --no-cache imagemagick-dev pcre-dev \
   && pecl install redis imagick \
   && docker-php-ext-enable redis imagick \
   && apk del autoconf pcre-dev build-base


RUN apk add libgomp


ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
   && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer


WORKDIR /var/www/html/app

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'


services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - .:/var/www/html/app
    networks:
      - app
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 9002:9000


  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    env_file: .env
    container_name: app-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html/app
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - app


  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    environment:
      ADMINER_DESIGN: lucas-sandery
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9001:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app
networks:
  app:
    name: 'app_api'
    driver: bridge


#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local

nginx.conf
events {
  worker_connections 2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  access_log off;
  client_max_body_size 64M;
  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache off;
  sendfile on;
  server_tokens off;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  tcp_nopush on;
}

I am new to Docker and these are my dockerfile, nginx.conf, and docker-compose.yml files code so when I build containers using these using docker compose up -d --build command the container becomes up but it gives me a 404 not found error when I hit the API route using localhost in 9000 port. Any solutions will be highly appreciated.



Can you show the url of endpoint/route you're hitting?

It looks like there is nothing wrong with your set up. Lets see how you write your php endpoints so we can reach them without 404 error

@ndotie sure the route that I am trying to hit is http://localhost:9000/api/v1/plan

It not only shows 404 not found error only in this route http://localhost:9000/api/v1/plan it shows same error in all the routes.

is it a laravel app?

If so we must have a way to expose index.php to nginx so that endpoints exposed to the world

Yes, it's a Laravel app. It's really frustrating I have been trying to resolve this issue from the past 3 days

Did you check whether static routes are mapped properly? What else did you try to spot the problem?

He's having 404 error on all routes @Nico Haase

@ndotie I've asked about static content within the container, to see whether this is a general routing problem (independent of Laravel or PHP) or a Laravel routing problem (where the PHP process is started, but the route is not resolved properly within Laravel)

@bhabishyachaudhary just to have this mentioned: PHP 8.1.2 on the basis of Alpine 3.15 is horribly outdated. Please try to updated your setup to supported versions, to ensure that you are not hitting any bug outside of your application

@Nico Haase can you please provide the proper code what things do I have to update in my existing code?

Depends on which problem you want to resolve. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

I am trying to resolve the 404 not found error whenever I hit the API route.

as per our discussion above i think we need to tweak our nginx conf file a little.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com; # This should be your domain

    root /var/www/html/app/public; #exposing endpoint to be reached since its laravel :)

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000; # Assuming your PHP-FPM container is named "app" and listens on port 9000
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

Hope it helps

root /var/www/html/app/public this line exposes index.php of laravel

It is giving me the same issue.
